# Is There Any Cross-Platform Framework That Can Reuse Existing React Components and CSS?

Tags: javascript, cordova, react-native, mobile, cross-platform

I have a web application that uses React/React-DOM and [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) components. I now need to build a cross-platform mobile application that shares functionality with the existing web application. So, I am looking for a "write once, run anywhere" framework to use in order to prevent building multiple UIs.

**Framework Requirements:**

1. The framework must be able to make use of the Semantic UI React library, css rules, and other existing React components targeting an HTML DOM.
2. The framework must allow me to build React components that can target browsers, iOS, and Android platforms.

The best solution I have found is to use [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) and a hybrid mobile app approach. This meets both of my requirements, but everything I have seen online seems to suggest abandoning Cordova (and hybrid apps in general) in favor of frameworks that can generate native UI elements. I am willing to live with the performance penalty that I would incur by choosing Cordova, but I am worried that it will not receive sufficient support or maintenance moving forward.

**Other Options**

1. [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) does not target browsers, so does not meet requirement 2.
2. [React Native for Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) would not support existing react components or CSS styles.
3. [ReactXP](https://microsoft.github.io/reactxp/) similarly does not support CSS styles

---

Am I mistaken to think that Cordova and hybrid apps are obsolete in 2018?

Should I bite the bullet and implement 2 UIs (one for mobile and one for web) with the shared business logic code?

Has anybody else solved a similar problem? If so, what framework did you choose?

Comment: If you don't need to access internal device API's a "*Progressive Web App (PWA)"*  using existing code base may work for you. Easy term to research.

Comment: Also easy to add an app icon on your phone home screen and try it out